# Oracle SQL Self Join advice

Tags: sql, oracle, self-join

This is my first question on this forum, so be patient...
My question is about the most efficient way to build a query on the following table:

```
create table OpenTrades(
    AccountNumber   number,
    SnapshotTime    date,
    Ticket      number,
    OpenTime    date,
    TradeType   varchar2(4),
    TradeSize   number,
    TradeItem   char(6),
    OpenPrice   number,
    TradeSL     number,
    TradeTP     number,
    TradeSwap   number,
    TradeProfit number  
);

alter table OpenTrades add constraint OpenTrades_PK Primary Key (AccountNumber, SnapshotTime, Ticket) using index tablespace MyNNIdx;`
```

This table is populated every 15 minutes, and the timestamp of the insert is saved in SnapshotTime column.
The sought query should group records by Week number (based on SnapshotTime), and filter the records so that it would return those with the latest (SnapshotTime) **within the same week**.

So far, I've tried the following:

```
select MyWeekNo(ot1.SnapshotTime), max(ot2.SnapshotTime) from OpenTrades ot1, OpenTrades ot2 where MyWeekNo(ot2.SnapshotTime)=MyWeekNo(ot1.SnapshotTime) group by MyWeekNo(ot1.SnapshotTime);.
```

( Note: MyWeekNo() is a slightly modified version of to_char(,'IW'). )

However, this takes way longer than expected (15 minutes for less than 1500 rows); I'm sure there's a much better way to write this, but so far, it has eluded me. Any idea?

Comment: Do you have index on `SnapshotTime` column?

Comment: Why are you joining at all? What does that gain you over just using `max(ot1.snapshottime)`? A virtual column with the (deterministic) `MyWeekNo()` value might help that too, even if that isn't indexed.

Comment: do you have execution plan for the query?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do a self-join at all. You'll get the same result with just:

```
select MyWeekNo(ot.SnapshotTime), max(ot.SnapshotTime)
from OpenTrades ot
group by MyWeekNo(ot.SnapshotTime);
```

You may find it useful to add a virtual column holding the calculated week number, but it won't have any performance impact for this query, and you wouldn't benefit from indexing either. With no filter you'd need to do a full table scan anyway, unless that calculated value and `SnapshotTime` were indexed, and that may not be desirable.

Your question suggests you might want other data from the latest rows in each grouped week, and you have multiple rows per snapshot. That might explain the self-join approach: you're initially just trying to find the latest snapshot date in each week and then plan to join back to find all rows with those snapshot dates? Though I may be misinterpreting that. If you are trying to do that though, you can use an analytic function to assign a ranking to each row based on the snapshot date and its week number, and then filter to only see those ranked first:

```
select WeekNo, SnapShotTime, AccountNumber -- and other columns
from (
  select ot.*, MyWeekNo(ot.SnapshotTime) as WeekNo,
    rank() over (partition by MyWeekNo(ot.SnapshotTime)
      order by ot.SnapshotTime desc) as Ranking
  from OpenTrades ot
)
where Ranking = 1
order by WeekNo, AccountNumber, Ticket;
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/33e28/1).

---

If a 'snapshot' can contain dates spanning a period of, say, 10 minutes, you could use an alternative analytic approach to get all records in the latest load:

```
select WeekNo, SnapShotTime, AccountNumber, Ticket
from (
  select ot.*, MyWeekNo(ot.SnapshotTime) as WeekNo,
    max(SnapshotTime) over (partition by MyWeekNo(ot.SnapshotTime)) as LatestEnd
  from OpenTrades ot
)
where SnapshotTime > LatestEnd - interval '10' minute 
and SnapshotTime <= LatestEnd
order by WeekNo, AccountNumber, Ticket;
```

Here `LatestEnd` from the inner query is the last `SnapshotTime` for the week, and the filter ignores anything that isn't between that time and ten minutes before it.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bbd2a/2) showing all five records from the most recent load selected, and those from the preceding load skipped.

Comment: this is useful, but it's not what I'm looking for; I need all the records from OpenTrades where SnapshotTime is between any 2 consecutive values returned from the query above...

Comment: @user3725166 - aren't records between two consecutive results going to be all records for that week number?

Comment: Thanks again Alex; perhaps some clarifications about my need are in order: SnapshotTime holds timestamps of each insert operation; every 15min or so, the feeding application inserts a bunch of records from each account, so that , by querying this table, I can get a sum of, say, TradeProfit for each 15min interval, and, for instance, build a chart out of it. I have no problems with this. My problem arises with a second set of requirements, namely the weekly reports, where

Comment: I need the snapshot of all open trades loaded into the table by the latest possible insert operation of the week (usually closing around Friday at 11pm), so I need to be able to associate a WeekNumber to any possible SnapshotTime (hence the need for MyWeekNo function), at the same time being able to select the latest "load" for that week. To further complicate the matters, the insert operation itself might span a few minutes, so I should also be able to sum up records from the same, say, 5 minutes range. I don't know, maybe I should try to work on the application side as well...

Comment: @user3725166 - well, the analytic approach gives you all records for the latest snapshot for each week, but assumes that the snapshot time is the same for all records inserted together; otherwise it isn't really a snapshot (?), and you might struggle to identify where one load ends and the next begins. Also not sure how that relates to the earlier two-consecutive-values comment.

Comment: @user3725166 - added another approach, but still not sure if I'm understanding what you need. Maybe adding some sample data (or creating a Fiddle) and the results you want to the question might help.

Comment: I think I finally got what I was after,though I had to resort to creating a view: `create or replace view VOpenTrades as select myweekno(snapshottime) WeekNo, accountnumber, max(snapshottime) WeekLastSnapshot from opentrades group by myweekno(snapshottime), accountnumber order by 1,2;` ; the final query that seems to work is: `select vot.WeekNo, ot.AccountNumber, ot.SnapshotTime, ot.Ticket from OpenTrades ot, VOpenTrades vot where ot.AccountNumber=vot.AccountNumber and ot.snapshottime between (vot.WeekLastSnapshot-10/1440) and vot.WeekLastSnapshot;` . Thanks for all the hints; you did help!

Comment: @user3725166 - same idea, my inner query is doing pretty much the same as your view. But you're hitting the table twice; the analytic approach only has to hit it once. (And it could use the analytic version of `max` instead of `first_value` if that's clearer; I'll change the answer to show that). For 1500 rows that probably doesn't matter too much though.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT   myweekno (ot1.snapshottime), MAX (ot2.snapshottime)
FROM     opentrades ot1
         JOIN opentrades ot2
            ON TO_DATE (ot1.snapshottime, 'IW') =
                  TO_DATE (ot2.snapshottime, 'IW')
GROUP BY myweekno (ot1.snapshottime);
```

You need to have index on `SnapshotTime` column.

Comment: Thanks Ambrish; I created the index as suggested, and tried the modified query; however, I saw no improvement in the response time (the query is still running, and it has been for over 20 minutes); am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from creating index on `SnapshotTime` column you can also try functional index on `MyWeekNo(OpenTrades.SnapshotTime)`.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_open_trades_snapshot_my_week ON OpenTrades(MyWeekNo(SnapshotTime));
```

Comment: Thanks tstr; I've tried that, but unfortunately I get an ORA-30553 (The function is not deterministic); MyWeekNo is in fact defined as follows: BEGIN
 if pDate>=to_date('291220130000','DDMMYYYYHH24MI') and pDate<=to_date('311220132359','DDMMYYYYHH24MI') then
  return 13.53;
 elsif pDate>=to_date('010120140000','DDMMYYYYHH24MI') and pDate<=to_date('040120142359','DDMMYYYYHH24MI') then
  return 14.01;
 else
  return to_number(to_char(pDate,'YY')||'.'||to_char(pDate,'IW'),'99.90');
 end if;
END;

Comment: @user3725166 - so why isn't your function declared as deterministic? If it's based on `IW` then it should be, surely; a given date passed in will always return the same result? If you have a lot of identical `snapshot_time` values then that could improve performance on its own.

Comment: @user3725166 If Oracle sees this function as not deterministic I don't think it will be able to optimize your original query in any way.

Comment: @AlexPoole : Thanks Alex, I wasn't familiar with the DETERMINISTIC clause; I recreated MyWeekNo() with it, and I was able to create the functional index on it; however, performance seems not to be affected, as the query has been running for over 15min... Am I doomed?

Comment: @user3725166 In your original question put screenshot or something that will show us what `EXPLAIN PLAN` for this query looks like (with which indices).

Comment: Only now have I realized that this join is unnecessary. And no additional indices should be needed...
edit: I see @AlexPoole already posted it in original question.